# Error al listar - PHP OOP

Tags: php, poo, pdo

Quiero mostrar los datos del usuario y a la vez listar los trabajos en donde se ha postulado. La primera parte se cumple, puedo mostrar los datos del usuario, pero tengo un problema para al querer listar los empleo en donde se ha postulado.

> ERROR: Warning: Illegal string offset 'titulo' in

Esto es lo hice hasta el momento:

Base de datos

Usuario DB

```
id | nombre
------------
1  | mario
```

Perfil DB

```
idperfil | idusuaio | email
--------------------------------------
1        | 1        | mario@email.com
```

Empleos

```
idempleo | titulo    | categoria
-----------------------------------
1        | operario  | metalurgica
2        | soldado   | metalurgica
```

Postulaciones

```
idpost   | empleoid  | usuarioid
------------------------------
1        | 1         | 1
2        | 2         | 1
```

PHP

```
<?php
class Sistema extends Db{

    public function obtenerUsuario($id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario 
            INNER JOIN perfil ON perfil.idusuaio = usuario.id 
            INNER JOIN postulaciones ON postulaciones.usuarioid = usuario.id 
            INNER JOIN empleos ON empleo.idempleo = postulaciones.empleoid
            WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($id));

        $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $resultado;
    }
}
?>
```

Index

```
<?php
$clase = new Sistema();
$id = 1;

$fila = $clase->obtenerUsuario($id);

echo 'Hola '.$fila['nombre'].', tu email es: '.$fila['email'];
// resultado: Hola mario, tu email es: mario@email.com
// BIEN

// LISTAR EMPLEOS POSTULADOS
foreach($fila as $row) :
?>

    <h5><?=$row['titulo'];?></h5>

   // ERROR: Warning: Illegal string offset 'titulo' in

<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Comprueba que `$row` contenga realmente un array y no un `string`...

Comment: Hago un `var_dump` de `$row['titulo']` y me dice que es un string `string(1) "1"`.

Comment: De ahí viene el error...

Comment: Espera, estoy tratando de entenderlo...

Comment: El bucle `for each` itera cada valor del array `$fila` y es por eso que `$row` es un string...

Comment: Comprendo lo que dices y perdón por mi ignorancia, pero no sé que debo hacer, estoy obnubilado.

Comment: Puedes usar un `foreach($fila as $clave => $valor)` y comparar `$clave` con 'titulo' para obtener su valor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La tabla usuarios contiene solo un registro que coincide con el ID buscado y, por lo tanto, solo te va a devolver una postulación. Lo que debes hacer es leer la tabla de postulaciones para obtener todos los registros de ese usuario:

```
public function obtenerPostulaciones($idUsuario){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM postulaciones
        INNER JOIN usuario ON postulaciones.usuarioid = usuario.id 
        INNER JOIN perfil ON perfil.idusuaio = usuario.id 
        INNER JOIN empleos ON empleo.idempleo = postulaciones.empleoid
        WHERE usuarioid = ?";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    // Leer todas las filas con fetchAll
    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $resultado;
}
```

Ahora, para mostrar los datos del usuario tomas el primer elemento:

```
$filas = $clase->obtenerPostulaciones($id);
// Verifica que se obtuvieron resultados
if(count($filas) == 0) {
    // Fin del script, aunque deberías hacer algo útil con esto
    die('El usuario no existe o no se ha postulado');
}
// Tomar la primera fila para mostrar los datos
echo 'Hola '.$filas[0]['nombre'].', tu email es: '.$filas[0]['email'];

// LISTAR EMPLEOS POSTULADOS, recorriendo todas las filas
foreach($filas as $row) :
?>
    <h5><?=$row['titulo'];?></h5>
<?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: Lo propio aquí sería agrupar en las tablas relacionadas. No es óptimo consultar `N` veces a otra tabla cuando puedes obtener todos los datos en una sola consulta. Este es uno de los fundamentos de las bases de datos *relacionales*. Combinando `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY` esto puede resolverse con suma facildiad, teniendo un código optimizado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tú necesitas aquí es una sola fila por cada usuario, y agrupar las coincidencias en las otras tablas relacionadas. Esto se puede lograr muy fácilmente combinando `GROUP_CONCAT` con `GROUP BY`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    class Sistema extends Db{
    
        public function obtenerUsuario($id){
            $sql = "SELECT 
                      u.nombre,
                      u.email,
                      p.email,
                      GROUP_CONCAT(e.titulo SEPARATOR '|') AS titulo
                    FROM usuario AS u
                    INNER JOIN perfil AS p ON p.idusuaio = u.id 
                    INNER JOIN postulaciones AS pt ON pt.usuarioid = u.id 
                    INNER JOIN empleos AS e ON e.idempleo = pt.empleoid
                    WHERE u.id = ?
                    GROUP BY u.id, u.nombre, p.email";
    
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array($id));
    
            $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
            return $resultado;
        }
    }
?>
```

Esta consulta **te traerá una fila por cada usuario** con esta estructura:

```
nombre      email                 titulo
------------------------------------------------------
mario       mario@email.com       operario|soldado
```

Como ves, **los títulos están agrupados en la fila** y separados por `|` (he preferido este separador a la coma u otros, porque puede haber títulos con coma). La consulta queda así optimizada, pues antes obtenías filas con `nombre` y `email` repetidos....

La lectura es tan simple como esto:

```
<?php
    $clase = new Sistema();
    $id = 1;
    
    $fila = $clase->obtenerUsuario($id);
    
    $html=sprintf("<p>Hola %s, tu email es: %s</p>",$fila['nombre'],$fila['email']);

    /*
       Como dijimos, los títulos vienen en una fila
       separados por |. 
       Con explode podemos crear un array
    */
    $titulos=explode("|",$fila['titulo']);
    
    /*
        Y con implode podemos rodear cada valor del array
        con la etiqueta html deseada, h5 en este caso
    */
    $html.=sprintf("<h5>%s</h5>",implode("</h5><h5>",$titulos));
    
    echo $html;
?>
```

No hay más historia, en `$html` tendrás esto:

```
<p>Hola mario, tu email es: mario@email.com</p>
<h5>operario</h5>
<h5>soldado</h5>
```

Y tendrás un código optimizado.

Comment: Muy interesante, sí, señor, cada día se aprende algo nuevo; ahora tengo material para investigar.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por la enseñanza y por su tiempo. Voy a poner en practica lo aprendido!!!